# After updagting my java version a lot of basic classes are not found

Tags: java, android, gradle

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.toString()
}
```

I updated my java version like up above.

Now when I try to build a bunch of my classes are broken.
[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: could you show java version in your system? Also, did you clean your project?

Comment: Invalidate caches restart?

Comment: How do I find my java version on my system @Alexander ? Yes I cleaned my project

Comment: Use command java --version